# Trying to convert a string number "7" to a 07:00 format with SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, simpledateformat

I've got the next java code:

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
    Date rangoInicio = formatter.parse(filtroHorariosIda.get(0));
```

The value for filtroHorariosIda.get(0) is "7" (quotes includes because it's a string)

The problem is java throws the exception

```
java.text.ParseException Unparseable date: "7"
```

I've been reading the java docs and I think it's a perfectly parsing operation. Where's the problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you're trying to parse "7" and saying that it should use "kk:mm" format.

Try this instead

```
Date rangoInicio = formatter.parse(filtroHorariosIda.get(0) + ":00");
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite understand... kk:mm expects something in the format, well kk:mm.  You're giving it "7".  Shouldn't you pass "7:21" instead (or "7:00" in this case)?

Answer (score 1):

your parse string expects an input containing ":" among other things - your input doesn't contain a ":" so of course SimpleDateFormat won't be able to interpret your input.

If your input was "7:0" it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, a simple test yields the following results:

```
public void testDateParse()
{
    String probes[] = {"7","07:00","7:00","7:0",":"}; 

    for (String probe : probes) {
        try
        {
         SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("kk:mm");
         Date rangoInicio = formatter.parse(probe);
         System.out.println(probe + " is parsable");
        }
        catch(ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println(probe + " is not parsable");
        }
    }       
}
```

7 is not parsable

07:00 is parsable

7:00 is parsable

7:0 is parsable

: is not parsable